# Angular 9 - How to get width of child elements during window size change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Is it possible to get the width of `.displayItemCol` when the user changes the window size?
I know its possible to get the width of .displayItemCol in `ngOnInit` using a reference variable but is it
possible to the width dynamically during window size change? I could try using the `ngOnChanges()` but that would detect any changes being made.

```
<div class="main" fxLayout="row">
  <div class="displayItemsCol" fxLayout="column">
    <app-applied-filter-bar></app-applied-filter-bar>
    <app-search-results-list></app-search-results-list>
  </div>

  <div class="displayItemCol" fxLayout="column">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following below but that was giving me the whole window width.

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event) class="displayItemCol" fxLayout="column" >

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

Comment: Could you create the demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your template HTML add #element to the div and then in your ts get the width of element like this:

```
@ViewChild('element', { static: true }) element: ElementRef;
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  console.log(this.element.nativeElement.clientWidth)
}
```